# Python Flask script auto-closes when run as .pyw file (workaround included)

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

### Problem

I've created a basic python script, using flask to render an HTML page. On Windows 10, the script works perfectly as a ***.py** file, but when run as a ***.pyw** file, the page is not rendered.

In Task Manager, instances of python are opened and closed within seconds after running the script as ***.pyw**.

---

### Code

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def main():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0", port=80)
```

---

### Workaround

Run the ***.py** version with the following lines added to the code:

```
import ctypes
...
...
...
if __name__ == '__main__':
  cytypes.windll.user32.ShowWindow(ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetConsoleWindow(), 0)
  app.run(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0", port=80)
```

Code above hides the console, and starts the flask app successfully.

---

However, I am still interested in an explanation as to why the ***.pyw** method won't work, if anyone has an idea.

Comment: That ctypes hack is great. I just wanted to run a webpage on my local network for personal use and have had an annoying console window always open on my machine forever. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.pyw-files would ran on `pythonw.exe` rather than `python.exe`. The difference is, that `pythonw.exe` does not run in a console by default and runs asynchronous. This would mean that flask starts and runs in the background untill everything else terminates. Since you to not have anything else in your application, the programm ends directly.

Comment: What do you mean "until everything else terminates" flask has an infinite loop in the run method, so it is itself running. Why does it exit?

Comment: your flask-server runs in another thread (asynchronous). The main-thread calls the run method and jumps directly to the next line. Since there is nothing else to do, the whole programm ends. python.exe waits untill all threads are terminated.

Comment: is there a way to keep the flask application alive using "pythonw" then?